# Match only A or B case insensitive

Tags: regex

I want a regular expression that validates a string of length 1 which has either the characters `A` or `B` (case insensitive) at the Begin

So this should return true

```
  A
  a
  B
  b
```

Any word would not match, so the following would return false:

```
 "America"
 "Bi"
 "a door"
```

Comment: And I want a million dollars :) What have you done so far?

Comment: Why can't you just compare your string to those four cases?  Regex seems like overkill for this.

Comment: Why is there a bounty on this question? It is not interesting nor challenging... @User2867655 - is this a mistake?

Comment: @Kobi I guess he wants to win a `Altruist` badge. :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `/^[AaBb]$/`. That's the simplest I know.

Comment: @Richard FYI `$` means "end of the string".

Answer (score 5):

Try this regular expression: `^[abAB]$`

Also you can use a case insensitive option (in Perl or Javascript): `/^[ab]$/i`

Comment: Or in all languages: `(?i)^[ab]$`.

Answer (score 5):

Since you want to match a fixed length of characters(in your case one), so you must use [Anchoring](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) on your regex using `^` and `$` or using `\A` and `\Z`. These means the start and end of a String(for simplicity). You can put your regex in between the anchors to match the whole string. For example:

```
^...REGEX...$
\A...REGEX...\Z
```

Now come to matching the character `A` or `B` in string. There are lot of ways to achieve this. Lets see few of them.

**Using [Character Class/Set](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):** Using this you can place multiple characters inside the `[]` and to pick only one character for the matching. So for your case the regex will be like below. It means any character from `A`, `a`, `B`, or `b`(which means any case).

```
^[AaBb]$
```

**Using [Alternating/Pipe](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):** This helps you to use `OR` condition in your regex, which means match one regex from multiple. Lets look at the below regex, here its using the characters in pipe.

```
^(A|a|B|b)$
```

**Using [modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html):** You can use modifiers in your regex to match both upper or lower case. That case you can use only `A` and `B` in your regex to match. Here I am using `(?i)` modifier to ignore the case.

```
(?i)^[AB]$
```

I want to believe that there will be plenty of more other ways to do that. You can find that using Google Search, or can wait for other Sagacious from this site to respond!

Comment: Your Alternating Pipe option needs to have brackets `^(A|a|B|b)$`

Comment: @sgauria Yeah, Thank you. Missed that. :-p

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `^` (start of the string) and `$` (end of the string) in your pattern:

```
/^[AB]$/i
```

where `i` modifier is a case insensitive flag, so you match only next chars:

- A
- B
- a
- b

Comment: This assumes that they are using JavaScript, Perl or PCRE. That assumption might not be true.

Answer (score -1):

This should not be done using regular expressions, as this is *not* a regular grammar; it is a [star free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-free_language) grammar.

Strictly speaking, there are no standard parsers or anything for star free grammars. Therefore, you should simply make your own using basic string checks available in your language.

For example:

```
bool test_for_ab_i(const std::string& input)
{
    if(input.length() > 1) return false;
    const char& test = input[0];

    if(test == 'a' || test == 'b' || test == 'A' || test == 'B') return true;
    return true;
}
```

This is almost certainly more efficient than even the most well optimized DFA or NFA; however, should you need to parse actual regular expressions as well, consider using [RE2](https://code.google.com/p/re2/). You'll find it a much better fit than anything Perl or PCRE compatible.